# Select object when a property equals Max with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

We have a query that selects rows depending on the value of another, ie. the max.  I don't think that really makes much sense, so here is the query:

```
var deatched = DetachedCriteria.For<Enquiry>("e2")
   .SetProjection(Projections.Alias(Projections.Max("Property"), "maxProperty"))
   .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("e2.EnquiryCode", "e.EnquiryCode"));

session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Enquiry), "e")
   .Add(Subqueries.PropertyEq("Property", deatched))
   .AddOrder(Order.Asc("EnquiryCode"));
```

My question is, is this the best way?  Can anyone suggest a better way?

Comment: I think that's the best way to do it.
In SQL you'd write: 
SELECT e.* from e WHERE e.Property = (SELECT MAX(e2.Property) WHERE e2.EnquiryCode = e.EnquiryCode)
and that's all you're doing in your HQL.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me with a similar issue (even though you have no answers!)

Answer (score 1):

For aggregations it is better to use SQL and not HQL.Use Nhibernate just for main Entities and their relations (very maintainable design) .Stored procedures are a better place to these aggregations and functions because they are data dependent and not object dependent

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with projection:

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Customer))
  .SetProjection( Projections.Max("Id") )
  .UniqueResult();
```

As described [Nhibernate Criteria: 'select max(id)...'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278276/nhibernate-criteria-select-maxid)

Answer (score 0):

I think this must work:

```
(from e in NHibernateSession().Query<Enquiry>()
    where e.Property == (
    (
        from e2 NHibernateSession().Query<Enquiry>()
        where e2.EnqueryCode == e.EnquiryCode
        select e2.Property).Max()
    )
    select e
).ToList<Enquiry>()
```